# Setting background image to a div in nextjs not working

Tags: html, css, jsx, next.js

I am new to nextjs and I dont understand why the background image is not being set for this div. In the root dir I have a folder called public, which I have the `art-thing.jpg` file in. `styles.css` is in the root dir. `index.js` is in the pages dir in the root dir. I can set the background to a color but I can not set it to a image. There is a post of someone with a similar problem but I would like my css to not be inline.

styles.css

```css
html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.page-container {
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
}

.page-container-welcome {
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url("/public/img/Branding/art-thing.jpg");
}
.content-wrap{
    padding-bottom: 2.5rem;
}
```

index.js

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import Head from 'next/head';
import HekateNav from "../client/components/nav";
import Footer from "../client/components/footer";

function Home() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Head>
                <title>Hekate</title>
            </Head>

            <div className="page-container-welcome">
                <div className="content-wrap">
                    <HekateNav/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <Footer/>
        </div>
    );
};
export default Home
```

console error that I get

```
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://localhost:3000/_next/static/css/bootstrap.min.css.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The solution was to change the path of the image by removing the public path. It was answered [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/webdev/comments/gqj8r2/setting_background_image_to_a_div_in_nextjs_not/). **Change path to /img instead of /public/image. /public is the actual root of the site in this case.**

```
.page-container-welcome {
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url("/img/art-thing.jpg");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.

step1.

> follow this link to install "next-images"
> https://github.com/twopluszero/next-images

```
//next.config.js

const withImages = require("next-images");
module.exports = withImages();
```

step2.

> import your target image and use it into custom styles like this code.

```
//index.js

import artImage from '/image/Branding/art-thing.jpg'
//don't use public folder to use static image, make 'image' folder in root path

const useStyles = makeStyles(()=>{
   pageContainerWelcome: {
      height: '100vh',
      background: 'url(' + artImage + ')',
      ...
      ...
   },
}
```